# "^[[201~" character being pasted at the end of file

Tags: neovim, filetype, paste

I'm trying to copy-paste by hand [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MichaelAquilina/zsh-you-should-use/master/you-should-use.plugin.zsh), but whenever I paste the contents in vim the last line shows this weird character at the end of the line `^[[201~`.
My guess is that it's one of those wrong conversion types between dos and unix, but this character is causing some strange behavior in vim.
As soon as I paste it and this character shows at the end of the file, vim goes to "INSERT COMPL" mode, and somehow I lose control over vim and I'm obligated to close the window, otherwise there's nothing I can do.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Does it work if you use `:set paste` before you go into insert mode to paste the file? Enabling `'paste'` mode should disable most of the special behavior Vim implements in insert mode and is meant to take all keystrokes verbatim, exactly how you'd want it if you're pasting large blocks of text possibly containing characters that Vim might try to have a special interpretation for...

Comment: Fill is most probably right and I believe we a duplicate about this issue on this website even though I can't find it right now.

Comment: @filbranden it still happens.. I paste it after entering paste mode and at the end this character is printed and I loose control over vim. Esc doesn't work, Ctrl+<anything> doesn't work, and the only solution is to close the terminal.

Comment: Actually, `^[[201~` is what a terminal usually sends for [bracketed paste mode](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#xterm-bracketed-paste), so maybe try to mess with some of those settings there... Perhaps `:set t_BE=` to disable bracketed paste mode will fix the issue for you?

Comment: It didn't work either, soo weird! I'm gonna try to make a GIF of the problem.

Comment: Please also post the output of `:set t_BE? t_BD? t_PS? t_PE?` which should tell us what those values are set to and whether they're set to something odd... Please also describe more about your environment, such as the operating system and which terminal emulator you're using, since that's potentially relevant with bracketed paste mode... Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can be related to [How to activate bracketed paste mode in GNOME Terminal for Vim inside tmux](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25311)?

Comment: possibly related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25157/71 also related about neovim stuck in bracketed paste mode: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/26418/71

Comment: @filbranden all of them outputs the same: `Key code not set: <t_BE?, t_BD?...>`.

Comment: I'm using LinuxMint 19, terminator, zsh and neovim

Comment: [This is my vim init file](https://pastebin.com/BUFxLAkh) but it doesn't matter since this happens to vim without configurations either

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yess, exactly same problem as the second link. But there it seems the problem wasn't even close to a solution.

Comment: So that's it, I'm getting stuck in bracketed paste mode

Comment: So I suppose this is Neovim (I have not heard of the same problem with Vim, but might also occur there). So what version is this? Also, bracketed paste mode should be able to finish, once it receives the end key sequences, e.g. `ESC` `[` `2` `0` `1` `~`. Not sure if you can enter that and try if this quits bracketed paste mode. In any case, you should report this after you have reproduced this on the latest version of either product with clear and exact reproduction steps.

Comment: Oddly enough, the problem stopped now. Maybe because of some of the tests recommended here.

Comment: Was having the same issue in neovim after paste some text. It had that `^[[201~` appended. No way to get out except quit. So odd and so annoying, tried all the the ways not working but it disappears after half an hour... Really curious why.